# app get turn off when i fetch data in arrayadapter through connection

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, okhttp

when i click on the this category fragment button in drawer when internet is available the app get close, and if internet connection is not available the it does not stop and shows no data available

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements OkHttpInterface {


ListView listcategory;
private TextView tvNoCategory;
private static String TAG = "categoryFragment";
ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModelArrayList;
private CategoryModel categoryModel;
String mstrpath;
private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container,false);
    init(rootView);
    return rootView;
}

private void init(View rootView) {

    listcategory = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frm_category);
    tvNoCategory = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_category);
    loadCategory();
}

private void loadCategory() {

    new OkHttpRequest(getActivity(),
            OkHttpRequest.Method.GET,
            ApiManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY,
            RequestCode.CODE_DISPLAY_CATEGORY,
            true, this);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onOkHttpStart(int requestId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onLoopjStart == 1" + requestId);



}

@Override
public void onOkHttpSuccess(int requestId, int statusCode, String response) {

    Log.e(TAG, "onLoopjSuccess == 1" + response);

    if (response != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonFetchAllCategory = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonFetchAllCategory.has("success")) {

                int code = jsonFetchAllCategory.getInt("success");

                Log.e(TAG, "code==1" + code);
                if (code == 1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "code==1" + code);
                    categoryModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                    if (jsonFetchAllCategory.has("path")) {
                        mstrpath = jsonFetchAllCategory.getString("path");
                    }

                    if (jsonFetchAllCategory.has("categories")) {
                        JSONArray jsonArrayData = jsonFetchAllCategory.getJSONArray("categories");

                        Log.e(TAG, "" + jsonArrayData.length());

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayData.length(); i++) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "" + 1 + "==========");
                            categoryModel = new CategoryModel();

                            JSONObject dataObject = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.i("contactsobject", "++" + dataObject);

                            if (dataObject.has("Category_id")) {
                                String mid = dataObject.getString("Category_id");
                                Log.e(TAG, "Category_id==" + mid);
                                categoryModel.setCategory_id(mid);
                            }
                            if (dataObject.has("Category_name")) {
                                String mStrname = dataObject.getString("Category_name");
                                Log.e(TAG, "category_id==" + mStrname);
                                categoryModel.setCategory_name(mStrname);
                            }

                            if (dataObject.has("Category_Photo")) {
                                String mStrImage = dataObject.getString("Category_Photo");
                                mStrImage = mstrpath + "" + mStrImage;
                                categoryModel.setCategory_photo(mStrImage);
                                Log.e(TAG, "image===" + mStrImage);


                            }
                            categoryModelArrayList.add(categoryModel);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (categoryModelArrayList.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < categoryModelArrayList.size(); i++) {
                            Log.e("IMAGE" + i + ":", categoryModelArrayList.get(i).getCategory_name());
                        }
                    }
                    listcategory.setAdapter(categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), categoryModelArrayList));

                    tvNoCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onOkHttpFailure(int requestId, int statusCode, String response, Throwable error) {

}

@Override
public void onOkHttpFinish(int requestId) {

}
```

}

This is  the code of category fragment and error i facing is like shown in below where i get all kind of data perfectly as per log but fail to lead to adapter

and this is the log file where error is defined

```
03-24 02:21:30.879 1628-1706/system_process E/ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: Unknown animationType=0
03-24 02:21:31.698 1309-3899/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
[ 03-24 02:21:31.702  3907: 3907 D/] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa29d5600, tid 3907
[ 03-24 02:21:31.737  3907: 3924 D/] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa29d57c0, tid 3924
03-24 02:21:39.527 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/OkHttpRequest: URL==>http://192.168.43.127/finaltheme/jsoncontroller.php?display_category
03-24 02:21:39.547 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: onLoopjStart == 1102
03-24 02:21:39.589 3907-3928/com.med_chains E/HTTPUtils:  URL:: http://192.168.43.127/finaltheme/jsoncontroller.php?display_category
03-24 02:21:39.754 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: onLoopjSuccess == 1{"categories":[{"Category_id":"3","Category_name":"Devices","Category_Photo":"Toshiba_HDTD105XK3D1_BLACK_LAPTOP_lg.jpg"},{"Category_id":"5","Category_name":"Medicines","Category_Photo":"195753.png"},{"Category_id":"6","Category_name":"Products","Category_Photo":"29178298_878820898990353_7940866216576036047_n.jpg"}],"success":1,"path":"http:\/\/192.168.43.127\/finaltheme\/images\/categories\/"}
03-24 02:21:39.755 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: code==11
03-24 02:21:39.755 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: code==11
03-24 02:21:39.756 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: 3
03-24 02:21:39.756 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: 1==========
03-24 02:21:39.762 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: Category_id==3
03-24 02:21:39.762 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: category_id==Devices
03-24 02:21:39.762 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: image===http://192.168.43.127/finaltheme/images/categories/Toshiba_HDTD105XK3D1_BLACK_LAPTOP_lg.jpg
03-24 02:21:39.762 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: 1==========
03-24 02:21:39.762 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: Category_id==5
03-24 02:21:39.762 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: category_id==Medicines
03-24 02:21:39.762 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: image===http://192.168.43.127/finaltheme/images/categories/195753.png
03-24 02:21:39.762 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: 1==========
03-24 02:21:39.762 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: Category_id==6
03-24 02:21:39.763 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: category_id==Products
03-24 02:21:39.763 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/categoryFragment: image===http://192.168.43.127/finaltheme/images/categories/29178298_878820898990353_7940866216576036047_n.jpg
03-24 02:21:39.765 3907-3907/com.med_chains E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.med_chains, PID: 3907
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:236)
at com.med_chains.CategoryFragment$1.run(CategoryFragment.java:145)
at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5849)
at com.med_chains.CategoryFragment.onOkHttpSuccess(CategoryFragment.java:140)
at hp.harsh.library.okhttp.OkHttpRequest$networkAsyncCall.onPostExecute(OkHttpRequest.java:238)
at hp.harsh.library.okhttp.OkHttpRequest$networkAsyncCall.onPostExecute(OkHttpRequest.java:200)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
03-24 02:21:40.325 1309-1309/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1309: eglCreateSyncKHR(1901): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

so this the whole logcat after click on categoryfragment

Comment: Could you try commenting out the e.printStackTrace(); on the JSONException?, based on the logcat, and your current code shown it's the most probable part to cause the error log.